# Packaged font doesn't load with @font-face

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

In a Chrome extension, I'm injecting a `<div>` into a page which I want to style with a font that's packaged in the extension.

The font file isn't being downloaded, and is falling back to the serif option in the font stack.

Could it be related to me using a shadow DOM?

style.css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Poppins-Medium';  
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/poppins-medium.woff2') format('woff');
    unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}

#wrapper {
    font-family: 'Poppins-Medium', sans-serif;
}
```

content.js

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('div');
myDiv.setAttribute('id', 'myContainer');
myDiv.setAttribute('style', 'all: initial;');
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);

var shadow = document.querySelector('#myContainer').attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

shadow.innerHTML = `
    <div id="wrapper">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="` + chrome.runtime.getURL('style.css') + `">
      <div>this text should be in poppins-medium</div>
    </div>
`;
```

manifest.json

```
{   
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension", 
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Blah.", 
    "icons": {
        "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My extension"
    },
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "content_scripts": [
    {
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "style.css",
        "poppins-medium.woff2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: "Could it be related to me using a shadow DOM?" - should be easy to try not using it and see.

Comment: @wOxxOm Good point. Tried without and same result. Will continue playing around

Comment: https://crbug.com/336876 might be related.

Comment: Ah I think you're right. If you submit as answer I'll mark as correct.